# What is the mean of this sentence "a return statement returns control to the calling function"

Tags: return

now I am reading about *return* in Microsoft docs.

but I can't understand a sentence "a return statement returns control to the calling function", especially the word control.

what does it mean and would you please give some examples of returning control?

thanks to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly which language you're discussing but they mostly follow the same behaviour, so consider the following pseudo-code, augmented with line numbers:

```py
1: def print_a_value(x):
2:     print(x)
3:     return
4: print_a_value(7)
5: print_a_value(9)
6: print_a_value(11)
7:
```

The flow of control (and "control" here can be thought of as the current bit of code being executed) is as follows:

- Program starts at line 1, defines the function, and ends up with control at line 4.
- Line 4 calls the function, remembering line 5 as the return point of the call.
- The function executes, printing "7", then returns to line 5. ***This*** is what is meant by "returns control to the calling function".
- Similarly, line 5 calls the function, which then returns to line 6.
- And line 6 calls the function, which then returns to line 7, and the program stops because there's no more code to run.